# Wildfly SSL protocol (TLSv1.2) configuration

Tags: ssl, wildfly, tls1.2, wildfly-8

I would like to know the correct way of configuring the SSL protocol on wildfly.

On looking at examples, I found two different ways of doing so. I want to know which one is the proper way of doing it -

Adding it in the protocol section as below:

```
<security-realm name="sslRealm">
            <server-identities>
                 <ssl protocol="TLSv1.2">
```

Or adding it in the https listener as below :

```
<https-listener name="https" socket-binding="https" security-
realm="sslRealm" enabled-protocols="TLSv1.2"/>
```

I'm using wildfly-8.2.0.Final.

Comment: Hi Deb! Welcome to StackOverflow!  Here, we usually don't include things like "Thanks" at the end of our questions, because they are just assumed. :) It cleans up the questions a little, making them quicker to read. Because of this community rule, I just edited your question quickly. Good luck with your question! :)

Comment: Do you find any applicable approach to solve your problem?

Answer (score 6):

> Configuration options shown here apply also to **Wildfly 9 and 10**

The correct way is using both of them. They are intimately related, see below how.

- **`<https-listener ..>`**

  The Wildfly Undertow subsystem support `enabled-protocols` attribute, which is a comma separated list of protocols to be supported. For example:

  `enabled-protocols="TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2"`

  *With just TLSv1.2, many vulnerabilities are plugged*. However, by default, Wildfly support all versions of TLS (v1.0, v1.1 and v1.2) even though versions below 1.2 are considered weak.
- **`<server-identities />`**

  Here, basically, you can choose one of the previously enabled protocols.

  ```
  <security-realm name="sslRealm">
      <server-identities>
          <ssl protocol="TLSv1.2">
  ```

  The `protocol` attribute by default is set to TLS and in *general does not need to be set*.

Note that without any change in the default configuration, you get a https server that supports TLSv1.0, TLSv1.1 and TLSv1.2.

For checking the effects of those configurations, use this:

```
nmap --script ssl-enum-ciphers -p 8443 <your wildfly IP>
```

Comment: That nmap script `ssl-enum-ciphers` is very nice to know about